# How to create a drop down list with "See more" button

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want a drop down list that will display, say first 3 items, then "See more" link, and when I click more items appended. I did searching around with `Twitter Bootstrap` and jquery but can't find any examples. Please help if any links of example or existing posts.

Comment: Please have a go yourself at writing a solution, then post your code and specify what exactly you got stuck at. Don't expect a full solution written for you based on a vague request.

Comment: ok thanks. I thought it should be 1 type of dropdown list in bootstrap that i can't find

Comment: what you can do is watch the value of the select box on change and if its the "seemore" value or something, then you append more option elements to the select element but you'll have to keep track of the elements yourself (edit: grammar)

Comment: Thanks @Daemedeor , will try this way to see if it looks nice

Comment: also because the UX/UI will be terrible otherwise, make sure you keep the selectbox open (via stoppropgation/stopevents) if the value is the see more elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**LATEST UPDATE - USING SELECT TAG :**

This one is completely different from the first one. But it is easier I guess. I hope this will help you.

```
<select class="form-control" id="itemList" onchange="addItems()">
    <option value="item1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="item2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="item3">Item 3</option>
    <option value="SeeMore" id="seeMore">See More</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
// Add more items here.
var addedItems = ["Billie Joe", "Mike Dirnt", "Tre Cool"];

function addItems(){

    if ($("#itemList option[value='SeeMore']").val() == "SeeMore") {

        // Removes the See more item.
        $("#itemList option[value='SeeMore']").remove();

        for (var i = addedItems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var theSelect = document.getElementById("itemList");
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = addedItems[i];
            option.attr = addedItems[i];
            theSelect.add(option);
        };
    };

}
```

**THIS ONE (BELOW) IS USING BOOTSTRAP DROPDOWN**

**OLDER UPDATE** here is a live sample [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/greenfoxx/xsjuzk6g/)

Here you can use a simple `dropdown` from bootstrap :

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
    Awesome!
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul id="yourList" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a id="seeMore" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">See more...</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Then add this `jquery`, it's self explanatory you can understand it very quick.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Add more items here.
var addedItems = ["Billie Joe", "Mike Dirnt", "Tre Cool"];

// When see more is clicked this methos was called.
$('#seeMore').click(function() {

    for (var i = addedItems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        // This removes the "See more" item on the list
        $('li').find('#seeMore').remove();
        // Appending the new items on the list
        $('#yourList').append(
            $('<li>').append(
                $('<a>').attr('href','#').append(
                    $('<span>').attr('class', 'items').append(addedItems[i])
        ))); 
    };

    // Re-open th dropdown after 5th of a second.
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('#dropdownMenu1').trigger('click.bs.dropdown'); 
    }, 200);
});
```

By the way here's the full code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css">

  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <br><br><br>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                        Awesome!
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul id="yourList" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a id="seeMore" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">See more...</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </section>


</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // Add more items here.
    var addedItems = ["Billie Joe", "Mike Dirnt", "Tre Cool"];

    // When see more is clicked this methos was called.
    $('#seeMore').click(function() {

        for (var i = addedItems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            // This removes the "See more" item on the list
            $('li').find('#seeMore').remove();
            // Appending the new items on the list
            $('#yourList').append(
                $('<li>').append(
                    $('<a>').attr('href','#').append(
                        $('<span>').attr('class', 'items').append(addedItems[i])
            ))); 
        };

        // Re-open th dropdown after 5th of a second.
        setTimeout(function() { 
            $('#dropdownMenu1').trigger('click.bs.dropdown'); 
        }, 200);
    });
</script>

</html>
```

```js
// Add more items here.
var addedItems = ["Billie Joe", "Mike Dirnt", "Tre Cool"];

// When see more is clicked this method was called.
$('#seeMore').click(function() {

  for (var i = addedItems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // This removes the "See more" item on the list
    $('li').find('#seeMore').remove();
    // Appending the new items on the list
    $('#yourList').append(
      $('<li>').append(
        $('<a>').attr('href', '#').append(
          $('<span>').attr('class', 'items').append(addedItems[i])
        )));
  };

  // Re-open th dropdown after 5th of a second.
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#dropdownMenu1').trigger('click.bs.dropdown');
  }, 200);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css">
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                        Awesome!
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
          <ul id="yourList" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Item 3</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a id="seeMore" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">See more...</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what i want. But the value i select is not shown.

Comment: Oh my bad, I will edit my answer please wait for update. :)

Comment: Great solution. I actually forked it (https://jsfiddle.net/xsjuzk6g/4/) and made some changes that I thought made the code just a little bit more readable/maintainable (namely, less chaining). What do you think?

Comment: Wow thanks @JoshBeam im falttered :) BTW im creating a new solution based on OP's actual problem, when I post the new answer maybe I wont remove this former answer in case someone will need this.

Comment: Wanted to add, too, the only changes I made were: using Array.prototype.forEach, removing the 200ms delay in the setTimeout, and using a function to return a string instead of chaining a lot of .append() methods.

Comment: Great! I'm glad you found the changes to be useful.

Comment: It's neater now. Thanks again :)

Comment: great one, will use this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [link](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-accordion.php), you'll find answer.
In see more section, use

```
$(selector).collapse('hide'/'show');
```

Hope this help

Thuc Tran

Comment: Collapse is not a good option, as it doesn't work in a select list.

Comment: i don't think this is what i want